# useDispatch is giving an error and I'm unable to add to my array

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

To try and understand Redux I've setup a simple todo project. Unfortunately I'm unable to get `useDispatch` to work.

I'm able to get all todo's I have stored with `useSelect` but I'm not able to add a todo because I think `useDispatch` is causing an error.

The error says: "`e.preventDefault()` is not a function" but when I remove `useDispatch` it doesn't display this error so I think the error is coming from `useDispatch`.

Here is the slice:

```js
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const slice = createSlice({
  name: "list",
  initialState: {
    value: [
      {
        id: 0,
        label: "Boodschappen",
      },
      {
        id: 1,
        label: "Scheren",
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        label: "Stoep vegen",
      },
    ],
  },
  reducers: {
    addTodo: (state, action) => {
      state.list = action.payload;
    },
  },
});

export const { addTodo } = slice.actions;

export default slice.reducer;
```

Here is the form component:

```
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { addTodo } from "../../slices/todoSlice";

function Form() {
  const list = useSelector((state) => state.list.value);
  const [todo, setTodo] = useState("");

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const addTodo = (e, addTodo) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch(addTodo([...list, { id: list.length + 1, label: todo }]));

    setTodo("");
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <FormWrapper>
        <form action="" onSubmit={(e) => addTodo(e, addTodo)}>
          <input
            type="text"
            name="todo"
            id="todo"
            value={todo}
            onChange={(e) => setTodo(e.target.value)}
          />
          <input type="submit" value="Add todo" />
        </form>
      </FormWrapper>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is the store I have setup. I did wrap it around my app component:

```js
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import listReducer from "../slices/todoSlice";

// config the store
const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    list: listReducer,
  },
});

// export default the store
export default store;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code isn't dispatching the `addTodo` you think it is. Instead of the imported `addTodo` action being passed to the local `addTodo` submit handler function, it's the local `addTodo` submit handler that is passed to itself and called in `dispatch` and it's subsequent call that is passed an argument that isn't an event object to call `preventDefault` on.

```
...
import { addTodo } from "./list.slice"; // <-- never referenced

function Form() {
  const list = useSelector((state) => state.list.value);
  const [todo, setTodo] = useState("");

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const addTodo = (e, addTodo) => { // <-- (1) this addTodo is in scope
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch(addTodo( // <-- (3) calls local addTodo without event object!
      [...list, { id: list.length + 1, label: todo }]
    ));

    setTodo("");
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <FormWrapper>
        <form action="" onSubmit={(e) => addTodo(e, addTodo)}> // <-- (2) addTodo passed to itself!
          <input
            type="text"
            name="todo"
            id="todo"
            value={todo}
            onChange={(e) => setTodo(e.target.value)}
          />
          <input type="submit" value="Add todo" />
        </form>
      </FormWrapper>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The fix is trivial, rename the submit handler to *anything* but the same identifier as the action you want to dispatch. You also don't need to pass the action through the submit handler callback's arguments since the `addTodo` action already has file scope.

```
...
import { addTodo } from "./list.slice";

function Form() {
  const list = useSelector((state) => state.list.value);
  const [todo, setTodo] = useState("");

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const submitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch(addTodo( // <-- imported addTodo action :)
      [...list, { id: list.length + 1, label: todo }]
    ));

    setTodo("");
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <FormWrapper>
        <form action="" onSubmit={submitHandler}>
          <input
            type="text"
            name="todo"
            id="todo"
            value={todo}
            onChange={(e) => setTodo(e.target.value)}
          />
          <input type="submit" value="Add todo" />
        </form>
      </FormWrapper>
    </div>
  );
}
```

There is also a typo in the list slice `addTodo` reducer. The list state is an object with a `value` property, so when updating the list's value you need to update `state.value` instead of `state.list`.

```js
const slice = createSlice({
  name: "list",
  initialState: {
    value: [ // <-- state.value
      ...
    ]
  },
  reducers: {
    addTodo: (state, action) => {
      state.value = action.payload; // <-- change
    }
  }
});
```

That said, it's uncommon to update the state the way you have. Instead of computing the next state value in the UI and passing the *entire* new value to the `addTodo` action, you should really dispatch only what you want to add and let the `addTodo` reducer function compute the next state. In other words, instead of duplicating the "addTodo" logic anywhere in the UI that wants to add a todo (*which is also prone to error*), you write the logic once in the reducer.

Example:

```js
import { createSlice, nanoid } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const slice = createSlice({
  name: "list",
  initialState: {
    value: [
      ...
    ]
  },
  reducers: {
    addTodo: {
      reducer: (state, action) => {
        state.value.push(action.payload); // <-- push todo into list
      },
      prepare: (label) => ({
        payload: { id: nanoid(), label }, // <-- create payload
      }),
    },
  }
});
```

Form

```
function Form() {
  const [todo, setTodo] = useState("");

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const submitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch(addTodo(todo)); // <-- dispatch just todo value
    setTodo("");
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <FormWrapper>
        <form action="" onSubmit={submitHandler}>
          <input
            type="text"
            name="todo"
            id="todo"
            value={todo}
            onChange={(e) => setTodo(e.target.value)}
          />
          <input type="submit" value="Add todo" />
        </form>
      </FormWrapper>
    </div>
  );
}
```

### Demo

[image: Edit usedispatch-is-giving-an-error-and-im-unable-to-add-to-my-array]